# docker postgres failed to start with specified port

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm new to docker and I'm trying to run a postgres database docker with the following command :

```
docker run --name rva-db  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=rva -e POSTGRES_DB=rva-db -d postgres -p 5432:5432
```

If I'm trying to run it without the -p option, it seems to work fine, but I can't reach it from my local pg-admin, I thought I need to add the port link to reach it.

Anyway, the container always crash after few seconds and when i'm trying to start it with the start command I'm getting the following return :

```
docker start -a rva-db
FATAL:  invalid value for parameter "port": "5432:5432"
```

What did I miss ?

FYI, I'm running it on a MacOS with the following docker version :

```
$ docker version
 Client:
  Version:      1.12.1
  API version:  1.24
  Go version:   go1.7.1
  Git commit:   6f9534c
  Built:        Thu Sep  8 10:31:18 2016
  OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

 Server:
  Version:      1.12.1
  API version:  1.24
  Go version:   go1.6.3
  Git commit:   23cf638
  Built:        Thu Aug 18 17:52:38 2016
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Run the container typing -p option before the image name

```
docker run --name rva-db  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=rva -e POSTGRES_DB=rva-db -d -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

As for [Docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) `docker run` has this format

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

Options must be before image name. After that you can set entrypoint or command (when theyy differ from default from Dockerfile) and their arguments.

Comment: it's seems to have worked.. But now I'm getting a password authentication failed.. Even if I copy/paste my password in the command and in the docker inspect.. Any idea ?

Comment: This is a different problem. Anyway I did a test and it works via jdbc locally. URL: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/rva-db  User name: postgres  Password: rva . To debug problems try "docker logs rva-db" or "docker exec -ti rva-db /bin/bash then look at the container. Refer to https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/ about instructions to run postgres containers based on officiale images. Hope it helps.